# Custom variables in a $group aggregation?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Given a `$group` aggregation pipeline stage like this:

```
$group: {
    _id: ...,
    hoursStreamed: { $sum: { $divide: [{ $subtract: ["$ts", { $max: ["$prev.ts", "$start"] }] }, 1000 * 60 * 60] } },
    hoursWatched: { $sum: { $multiply: [{ $divide: [{ $subtract: ["$ts", { $max: ["$previous.ts", "$start"] }] }, 1000 * 60 * 60] }, "$viewers"] },
}
```

Is it possible to somehow assign the result of the repeating computation

```
{ $divide: [{ $subtract: ["$ts", { $max: ["$prev.ts", "$start"] }] }, 1000 * 60 * 60] }
```

to a variable that could be used in both `hoursStreamed` and `hoursWatched`?

I don't see how `$let` could be used in this case as we need the result in more than one field.

Comment: Do you need something like this: [MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/nIEmGfiNFL4)?

Comment: @Valijon `$let` returning a document combined with a following `$replaceWith` stage could work. But not as straightforward as I hoped.